# Replace only 1 leading zero, if it's more than 1 times then discard it

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, sh

I want ot replace exactly 1 leading zero with @, if 2 or more leading Zeros found then discard it.

```
0123
00123
000123
123
```

Output:

```
@123
00123
000123
123
```

I have tried

```
sed 's/^0.\{1\}/@/' file
```

Note : Please conside above 4 records in each line of file.

Comment: `sed '/^00/!s/^0/@/' file`

Comment: Thanks, above code is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

One in awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/^0/,(/^00/?0:"@"))}1' file
@123
00123
000123
123
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '{sub(/^0/,(/^00/?0:"@"))}1' file
        |    |       |  |  |
        |    |       |  |  otherwise with a @
        |    |       |  with a zero
        |    |       if followed by a zero
        |    leading zero
        replace
```

and if it is in the second `|` delimited field, use:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{sub(/^0/,($2~/^00/?0:"@"),$2)}1' file
1|@123|1
2|00123|2
3|000123|3
4|123|4
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have included a single 0 on it's own line in your sample input as that's an edge case that could be missed:

```
$ cat file
0123
00123
000123
123
0

$ sed -E 's/^0([^0]|$)/@\1/' file
@123
00123
000123
123
@
```

The above will work with any sed that has a `-E` option to use EREs, e.g. GNU sed and BSD/OSX sed.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex looks for a zero, followed by any character. You want to check that it is not  followed by a zero,  but not replace the nonzero character.

You can capture and put back the character you want to keep:

```
sed 's/^0\([^0]\)/@\1/' file
```

Or you can take care to only replace the first character on lines which match this regex:

```
sed '/^0[^0]/s/^0/@/' file
```

As ever, specifying that something is repeated exactly once is pointless and redundant.

Comment: I have one more Problem here, above column is in 2nd Position in file. means data Looks like 101|0123

Comment: Then use `|0` instead of `^0` (assuming that there are exactly two columns). You really need to show the actual data in the question to get answers which work for your data!

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ cat lead_zero.txt
0123
00123
000123
123
0
$  perl -pe ' s/(^0)(?!0+.*)/@/ ' lead_zero.txt
@123
00123
000123
123
@
$
```

If it is in second column of a pipe delimited file, then use this.

```
$ cat lead_zero.txt2
a|0123|x
b|00123|y
c|000123|xx
d|00000123|yy
e|123|zz
f|0|qq
$ perl -pe ' s/(.*?\|)0(?!0+.*)/$1@/ ' lead_zero.txt2
a|@123|x
b|00123|y
c|000123|xx
d|00000123|yy
e|123|zz
f|@|qq
$
```